# How to make PostgreSQL case insensitive?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu, case-insensitive

How to make PostgreSQL search (`WHERE field = 'stackoverflow'`) case insensitive?

I don't want to use `LOWER()` because of ORM and CITEXT because of less efficiency. I found the solution is to use another collation:

```
CREATE DATABASE polish_database  LC_COLLATE 'pl_PL.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE
'pl_PL.UTF-8';
```

But how to download case insensitive collation/locale to Ubuntu?

Comment: what you mean locale to Ubuntu? That collate give you an error?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html

Comment: If you really want to define a custom locale, you can start here: [The Open Group Base Specifications: Locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html). Check also [Locale Helper](http://lh.2xlibre.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this help.

But you dont need use the collate for the whole database.

you can asign the collate just to the field you are worry about it.

```
CREATE TABLE test1c (
    id integer,
    content varchar COLLATE "x"
);
```

Also you can create an index to support collate or with a calculate value

```
CREATE INDEX test1c_content_y_index ON test1c (content COLLATE "y");
```

OR

```
CREATE INDEX test1c_content_y_index ON test1c (LOWER(content));
```

Then you can do `lower()` and use index.

```
WHERE field = Lower('StackoverFlow')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be used keyword **ILIKE**.

```
select 'test' ILIKE 'TEST'; // return true
```